# Can't access Express.js route from localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a client/server app and I have a MongoDB running and connected. For some reason I can't access the admin route I created when running my app in development mode. My dev url is for example `localhost:8082` and when I try to access the `admin` route by going to `localhost:8082/admin` I get a blank page and when I try `api.localhost:8082/admin` I get the error `Invalid Host Header`.

Now on the live app for example, when it's deployed I can access the admin route by going to : `api.nameofdomain.com/admin`

I'm not sure what I need to change in my Express.js Server code to get to the admin route from localhost.

This is my `routes/index.js` file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const mongoose = require('../db/db.js')
const ActivityLog =  require('../db/ActivityLog.js')
const Song =  require('../db/Song.js')
const Meta =  require('../db/Meta.js')

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
const marked = require('marked')
const parse = require('csv-parse')
const energyEq = require('../special/energy-eq.js')

const archiver = require('archiver')
const path = require('path');

sgMail.setApiKey('blah')


// crud admin
router.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
  res.render('login')
})

router.post('/admin', function(req, res) {
  const { password } = req.body
  if (!password) return

  if (password === 'blah') {
    req.session.authenticated = true
    res.redirect('/dashboard')
  }
})

// Helper to check if user is logged in
const isAuthorized = (req, res, next) => {
  if (
    (req.session && req.session.authenticated) ||
    req.connection.remoteAddress === '::1'
  )
    return next()

  return res.redirect('/admin')
}



const createOrUpdateMeta = (title, content, res) =>
  Meta.findOne({
    title
  })
  .then(field => {
    if (!field) {
      return Meta.create({
        title,
        content
      })
    }

    return Meta.update({ title }, { $set: { content } })
  })
  .then(_ => res.redirect('/dashboard'))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    return res.sendStatus(400)
  })

// updater
const metaUpdater = (title, req, res) => {
  const { content } = req.body
  return createOrUpdateMeta(title, content, res)
}

// Get Term Equivalences
router.get('/terms', function(req, res) {
  return _getMetaFromTitle('terms')
    // get and parse it
    .then(data => data.content.replace(/\r/g, ''))
    .then(content => content.split(/\n/).map(row => row.split(', ')))
    .then(termEquivalences => res.json({ termEquivalences }))
})


module.exports = router;
```

This is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var session = require('express-session');
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();


// Allow CORS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Cache-Control'
  )
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers',
    'Authorization'
  )
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')

  // intercept OPTIONS method
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.status(200).send('')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

app.use(fileUpload())

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'fdfdyrt',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.url.includes('/songs/') && req.query.dl) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment')
  }
  return next()
})
app.use(stylus.middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/pre', require('./routes/pre'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.sendStatus(err.status || 500);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is the auth.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const c = require('../controllers/handler')
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const passportJWT = require('passport-jwt')
const JWTStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy
const ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const jwtSecret = `bla32` // @TODO L change to secure
const passportOpts = { session: false }

const User =  require('../db/User.js')
const ActivityLog =  require('../db/ActivityLog.js');
const { db } = require('../db/User.js');

/** Get details of currently logged in user */
const getCurrentUser = async (id) => {
  const user = (await User.findById(id))
  delete user.password
  return user
}

/**
 * Register a new user on the platform
 */
const register = async ({ email, password }) => {
  const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email })
  if (existingUser) {
    console.log(existingUser, email)
    throw new Error('Email already exists')
  }
  const newUser = await User.create({
    email,
  })
  newUser.setPassword(password)
  await newUser.save()
  return true
}

/**
 * Track any downloads on site
 */
const trackDownload = async (email, title) => {
  if (!email || !title) return false
  await ActivityLog.create({
    type: 'download',
    email,
    title,
    downloadedAt: new Date(),
  })
  return true
}

/** Auth middleware for login, register */
const authorizeMiddleware = (passport) => {
  /** Passport strategy for all auth */
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true,
      },
      async (req, email, password, done) => {
        try {
          const type = req.url.includes('login') ? 'login' : req.body.type || 'login'

          if (type === 'register') {
            try {
              if (!email || !password) throw new Error
              await register({ email, password })
            } catch (e) {
              console.error(e)
              return done(null, false, { message: 'User already exists' })
            }
          }

          // find and login to the user
          const user = await User.findOne({ email })

          if (!user || !user.validatePassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid email or password' })
          }

          return done(null, user.toJSON())
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e)
          return done(e)
        }
      }
    )
  )

  /** Verify token middleware */
  passport.use(
    new JWTStrategy(
      {
        secretOrKey: jwtSecret,
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      },
      async (payload, next) => {
        return next(null, {
          _id: payload._id,
          email: payload.email
        })
      }
    )
  )

  return (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, async (err, user, info) => {
      if (err || !user) {
        console.error(err)
        return res.status(400).json({ message: !!info ? info.message : 'An error occured' })
      }

      req.login(user, { session: false }, async (e) => {
        if (e) {
          console.error(e)
          return res.send(e)
        }
        // only sign the _id
        const token = jwt.sign({
          _id: user._id.toHexString(),
          email: user.email
        }, jwtSecret)
        // but send entire data
        return res.json({ access_token: token })
      })
    })(req, res, next)
  }
}

//
// Routing
//

router.post('/login', authorizeMiddleware(passport))

router.post('/register', authorizeMiddleware(passport))

// Return the currently logged in user
router.get('/user', passport.authenticate('jwt', passportOpts), c(getCurrentUser, (req) => [req.user._id]))

// Download
router.post('/dl/trc', passport.authenticate('jwt', passportOpts), c(trackDownload, (req) => [req.user.email, req.body.title])),


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `api.localhost` is not a valid host name `localhost` is shorthand for `127.0.0.1` which is an IP whereas `api.whatever.com` is a dns name leading to an `ip` address

Comment: remove the `api` before `locahost` and it should work properly

Comment: I figured it out. the server was running on a different port so it worked on localhost:3030/admin. Thanks